# React js map image in img tag

Tags: reactjs

I need to map some images into one img html tag but when i render the result in the image src the result is [Object Object], i've tried all the example i've found on the web but nothing helped me.The images i need to put in the img tag are in the img folder and the path i put in the list is right, I tried to hard put the path in the img and it work. my code is this:

Card.js

```
    import CustomData from './PortfolioList'
    
export default function PortfolioCard(){
return(
    CustomData.map((portfolio, key) => (
        console.log(portfolio),
        <Col key={key}  span={6}>
        <a href="#" className="portfolio-inner">
        <div className='text-container'>
          <div className='text-inner'>
        <h2>
          {portfolio.name}
        </h2>
        <hr style={{width:'30%', marginTop:0}}/>
        <GraphicTag/>
        </div>
        </div>
          <img src={portfolio.img} style={{
            backgroundPosition:' center center',
            backgroundSize:'contain',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            width:'100%',
            height:'100%',
        }}/>
        </a>
        </Col>
    
        ))
)
}
```

and this is my List

```
const PortfolioList =  [{
        id: "1",
        name: "Sanguis wine",
        type: "graphic design",
        img:'../img/sanguis-copertina.jpg',
        },
        {
        id: "2",
        name: "Underground Festival",
        type: "Graphic Design",
        img:'../img/sanguis-copertina.jpg',
        },
        {
        id: "3",
        name: "Lotus Logo",
        type: "graphic design",
        img:require('../img/sanguis-copertina.jpg'),
        },
        {
        id: "4",
        name: "Cocktail app",
        type: "Web design",
        img:require('../img/sanguis-copertina.jpg'),
        },
        {
            id: "5",
            name: "Portfolio site",
            type: "web design",
            img:require('../img/sanguis-copertina.jpg'),
                
}]

export default PortfolioList
```

UPDATE
I've found that i can find the image path only in http://localhost:3000/static/media/image.jpg. If i use the correct path the image don't appear

Comment: in your Portfolio list, you have img that points to absolute path, and img with require(), perhaps you want to work on debugging the most obvious mistakes first (inconsistent codes), on your own.

Comment: i've removed the require and tried to use various path but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the images in your public folder, then point it to the correct directory. In your case, the images should reside in `/public/img/`

then your object should be

```
{
        id: "4",
        name: "Cocktail app",
        type: "Web design",
        img: '/img/sanguis-copertina.jpg',
        }
```

Comment: what set up are you using? create react app? https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Answer (score 2):

Remove *require* and give an absolute path to the image.

Comment: i've tried like you recommended but it doesn't work, in the src when I inspect object the address appears but don't show the image

Comment: Copy the image address and check whether the image address is correct or not.
probably your image path is not correct, I think.

Comment: i've copied the path but don't find the image. idk